# Change default GTK3 CSS for showing tabs smaller

Tags: gtk, gtk3

All these GTK 3 elements are taking much too many space around anything, wasting my screens entropy. I am searching for the way to change the default GUI config, CSS, or whatever used by GTK to globally (anything in user session would also be OK) determine how much space is around something, e.g. around the text in program tabs.

*Is* there a way without changing source code of some libs (if only via libs -
 which)?

Answer (score 0):

The GTK CSS config is available at `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`, which can be freely edited by any text editor.

In order to know what element to change, however, you will need to use a tool like GTK Inspector to locate the proper classes/IDs.